# Which shell script executes first at boot time?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there a standard entry point of the shell in Linux?

For example I know that /etc/profile get executed at startup, but which is the script that gets executed first?

If every distro does it differently, what is the behavior in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

This are the sequence of events that happen during boot in Linux (I think it is the same for all distros)
1. The BIOS or boot-loader which loads the Linux kernel
2. The Linux kernel identifies hardware connected to the system
3. Kernel mounts the `/root`
4. `/root` contains /etc/inittab which defines the run-level and /etc/fstab which defines the file systems in the system which are executed
5. Based on the run-level (usually 3 for graphics environment), the scripts in /etc/rcN.d directories are executed.
Check this site for more interesting information http://www.tldp.org/

Comment: Keep a watchful eye on the dates of the info on tldp.org; the older the more plausible to be outdated.